# Implement dynamic SP, IDP

Tags: spring-saml

I've implemented spring SAML 2.0 in my system with multiple SP, IDP .
I need to move CachingMetadataManager on security-context.xml to bean and load data from DB, and need to update metadata on runtime.

The same like Salesforce add ,edit, remove Service Provider.

How to do that ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

In M17 of the 2.0.0 release train its very simple to override the `getConfiguration` method in the configuration filter.

Here is an example

https://github.com/karanb192/spring-security-saml/blob/1ad7289bcfaf97c001d78283e8ef9aa93ae6e6a3/samples/boot/simple-service-provider/src/main/java/sample/config/OktaMultitenantSamlConfigurationFilter.java#L9

https://github.com/karanb192/spring-security-saml/blob/1ad7289bcfaf97c001d78283e8ef9aa93ae6e6a3/samples/boot/simple-service-provider/src/main/java/sample/config/MultiTenantConfigurationRepository.java

Comment: Please add sample code or a more fleshed out answer rather than providing links, as the links may go down in the future.

Comment: This still is not released. Do you know of a way to do this with the released version of Spring Security Saml?